# downloading a file in python via a http get request

Tags: file, python-2.7, http, download, urllib2

I am downloading a file using HTTP Get request. When doing this on the browser, it takes few seconds for a file to generate and the response header contains: *Content-Disposition: inline;filename="file.zip"*

My python code downloads the file using:

```
response = opener.open(api_url,timeout=20)
content = response.read()
with open("file.zip","w") as fp:
    fp.write(content)
```

However the file.zip I have locally ends up being a corrupted file. Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However I don't have URL for a filename. I generate a http get request which results in API returning a file for download. File size of the file I write to the disk is smaller than the actual file which makes me wonder if I need to handle this in some different way.